How to sort React attributes in VS Code?
For example I got:
<Image
 alt=""
 src="/img/logo.svg"
 width="30"
 height="30"
 className="d-inline-block align-top"
 />

Any plugin to sort these attributes according to some rules, such as alphabetical order, type, etc.? I am using VS Code, ESLint and Prettier.

First select the lines you want sorted, then press
ctrl + shift + p (or cmd + shift + p on mac) to open command palette in vscode. Search for Sort Lines Ascending (or Descending).


It only works on single-line attributes. Do you know a solution for multi-line attributes?

No, sorry... :(

Try to use ESLint Perfectionist and sort-jsx-props rule:
https://perfectionist.dev/rules/sort-jsx-props
There information about usage with VS Code:
https://perfectionist.dev/guide/integrations#visual-studio-code
